# How do I change the size of buttons without the buttons overlapping each other?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have a dialog box that is giving users 3 options,  yes, no , cancel ..
I change the yes , no to a new caption weapon1 and weapon 2.  I also change the width of the buttons to match the width of the new caption. But if the new caption is too long , the buttons just over lap. How do i solve this?

```
  Weapon1 := FMyPlayers.player[FGamePlay.chartoattackwith].Values['Attack1'];
  Range1 :=  FMyPlayers.player[FGamePlay.chartoattackwith].Values['Range1'];
  Weapon2 := FMyPlayers.player[FGamePlay.chartoattackwith].Values['Attack2'];
  Range2 :=  FMyPlayers.player[FGamePlay.chartoattackwith].Values['Range2'];
    with CreateMessageDialog('Please pick a weapon:', mtConfirmation, mbYesNoCancel) do
        try
          TButton(findcomponent('Yes')).Width := self.Canvas.TextWidth('    '+Weapon1+':'+range1+'    ');
          TButton(findcomponent('No')).Width :=  self.Canvas.TextWidth('    '+Weapon2+':'+range2+'    ');
          TButton(FindComponent('Yes')).Caption := Weapon1+':'+range1;
          TButton(FindComponent('No')).Caption := Weapon2+':'+range2;
         case ShowModal of
           mrYes: AttackValue := '1';
           mrNo:  AttackValue := '2';
           mrCancel: exit;
         end;
        finally
       Free;
     end;
```

Comment: Obiously, you also have to change the button positions. Use the `Left` property.

Comment: i think it maybe more then that.. its almost like the messagebox is not growing big enough for the buttons..? Also the size of the caption changes, how would i use the left property accordingly..

Comment: Why use FindComponent? Better use fields of the form object.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i am not too advance, so dont get upset when i say this.. I have no clue how that would help me.. But i used findcomponent due to it being a dialog box , and i did not know any other way to update the property's of that dialog box..

Comment: Gah, you are right of course. I had not seen that. Sloppy from me. Sorry. In that case add a couple of local variables, NoBtn and YesBtn say. Makes the code more readable.

Comment: although it is solvable, it feels like making cows to look alike a sheep. Using an own Form would avoid that hassle

Comment: You might be better off using the Vista task dialog for this. Let the system arrange your buttons. TTaskDialog in Delphi I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

insert this part of code

```
  TButton(findcomponent('No')).Left := TButton(findcomponent('Yes')).Width + TButton(findcomponent('Yes')).Left;
  TButton(findcomponent('Cancel')).Left := TButton(findcomponent('No')).Width + TButton(findcomponent('No')).Left;
  Width := 2*TButton(findcomponent('Yes')).Left + TButton(findcomponent('Cancel')).Left + TButton(findcomponent('Cancel')).Width;
```

according to David Heffernan

```
var
No,Yes,Cancel:TButton;

.....
No := TButton(findcomponent('No'));
Yes := TButton(findcomponent('Yes'));
Cancel := TButton(findcomponent('Cancel'));

No.Left := Yes.Width + Yes.Left;
Cancel.Left := No.Width + No.Left;
Width := 2 * Yes.Left + Cancel.Left + Cancel.Width;
```

Comment: perfect! Works exactly how i was hopeing!

Comment: Please read those FindComponent return values into some local variables.